# AcquireToken() from Background Job

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-webjobs, adal

I am using Azure Active Directory and [ADAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573266.aspx) to interact with Exchange EWS of Office 365 with OAuth.

I know you can use `authContext.AcquireToken()` and It will manage all oauth for you. It will save, use, and refresh, tokens for you and also prompt to the user credentials when is required. The issue in my case is that I need the interaction in an Azure background web job so It wont be able to ask for the user credentials.

What I tried was getting the authorization code making the user visit the url from `GetAuthorizationRequestURL()`. Then getting a Token using `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode()` and saving the Refresh Token in the database. So  when the background Job needs to connect to EWS it can use the Refresh Token (saved in the Db) using `AcquireTokenByRefreshToken()`.

This approach works but I dont know how you can get a new Refresh Token when it expires after 14 days.

Any idea of how can I renew the refresh token or a better approach for using ADAL in a Background Job?

Thanks and regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there's an idea. Create a simple console or win form app that requests your token. In that app, use a custom cache that saves tokens in a portable store (like an encrypted file, see https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet). Run the app once to seed the cache. Then take that cache and deploy it together with your web job. Now for 90 days or so you'll be fine.
Another alternative is to use username/password flows but that's rarely a good idea and it entails many important limitations.

Comment: The issue about this, is that the app is not only for me. What we want is the user go to the website an 'Authorize' access to their office 365. Then a background job will be do something every night..  That's why credentials and oauth process should be prompt in the website but use of the tokens are in the background job. Any idea?

Comment: Ah then that's easy. Just share token cache between web site and background job. Acquiretokensilent does use and renew refresh tokens. Just take https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet and have the logic running in the controllers run in your background job. The important thing is that both web site and job work with the same cache instance.